# Was there ever a "breaking change" in the Java language specification?

Tags: java, jls

With the problably widely known exception of the introduction of the 'assert' keyword, has there ever been a change in the Java language specification which caused old code to be no longer compatible with newer source levels of the JDK?

---

Summary so far (many thanks for the comments):

"Older" Java code can cause compilation errors, when upgrading to a later version, if the code uses declarations using one of the keywords which where introduced in a later version of the Java language specification (JLS):

- assert
- enum
- strictfp

Comment: enum comes to mind as well.

Comment: [strictfp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strictfp). It was default before 1.2

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/index.html

Comment: the java nio saves a lot of code

Comment: @Dima Goltsman, nio did not introduce any *language* changes. `assert` and `enum` are keywords, so their introduction broke old code that used these words as identifiers. For example `enums` library from Jakarta Commons.

Comment: Also there was a change in behavior of @Override annotation.

Comment: Created answer to summarize, can't really think of anything else at the moment (good point for Java). @javadeveloper changing Override behavior didn't break compatibility.

Comment: @javadeveloper The @ Override change didn't break existing code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Java 1.2

- `strictfp` keyword.

### Java 1.4

- `assert` keyword.

### Java 1.5

- `enum` keyword.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that `_` was designated a "keyword" in Java 9. See https://blogs.oracle.com/sundararajan/underscore-is-a-keyword-in-java-9%2c-use-this-script-to-check-your-code

Answer (score 3):

Java 10 made `var` a keyword. It's still a valid variable name but an illegal class name.